# Redirect all emails according to a database

Tags: mysql, debian, email, database

Let's say I own `example.com` and I have a MySQL or SQLite database (updated every now and then via PHP):

```
user0001    abc@gmail.com    
user0002    def@gmail.com
user0003    ghi@yahoo.com
...
(a few thousand items)
```

**What are the common Linux used tools to make that an email arriving to `user0001@example.com` is redirected to `abc@gmail.com`, etc.?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a mail server that is driven by db tables, or arrange to export your db tables in an appropriate format every so often.

Lots of ways to do this, but the way I use and seems to be fairly common is a Postfix+Dovecot+Mysql solution.  If you need/want a nice admin interface for it all, look at ISPConfig.  Overkill - maybe - but it works well.  If nothing else, the server setup pre-requisites will get you 3/4 of the way to a roll your own solution.

Comment: Thanks @ivanivan. Without ispconfig (I'd prefer to do it manually), how would make the link between mysql and dovecot? With bash or python or simply in a dovecot configuration file? Thanks in advance if you can add a little code.

Comment: @Basj All in the postfix adn dovecot configuration - for a non-ISPConfig version, a similar set up is at https://workaround.org/ispmail/jessie .  Haven't tried the directions on a Stretch system, but I've successfully dist-upgraded from Jessie to Stretch on a system configured this way with no breakage.

Comment: Thanks for this link. I've looked at it but it also covers having real mailboxes, query with pop or imap, etc.,  round cube, etc. This is probably too big solution because all I want is to redirect email (and not provide imap pop webmail). Isn't there a smaller solution?

Comment: Just don't populate those tables with data.... don't install roundcube, etc